# Getting error BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: as soon as I expose clientRegistrationRepository bean in my spring boot security configuration

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I am trying to configure oauth2 login flow in my application. The problem is default configuration is working but as soon as I expose clientRegistrationRepository bean I got the error. First here is my POM.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
                    https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<groupId>pk.training.basit</groupId>
<artifactId>Ch-02-SpringBootOAuth2ResourceServerWithIntrospection</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>SpringBootOAuth2ResourceServerWithIntrospection</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>14</java.version>
    <oauth2-oidc-sdk.version>8.15</oauth2-oidc-sdk.version>
    <mssql-jdbc.version>8.3.1.jre14-preview</mssql-jdbc.version>
    <jjwt-api.version>0.11.2</jjwt-api.version>
    <bootstrap.version>4.5.0</bootstrap.version>
    <jquery.version>3.5.1</jquery.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- do you like thymeleaf? -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- optional, it brings userful tags to display spring security stuff -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
    </dependency>
      
    <dependency>
        <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.nimbusds</groupId>
        <artifactId>oauth2-oidc-sdk</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
        <version>${jjwt-api.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
        <version>${jjwt-api.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId> <!-- or jjwt-gson if Gson is preferred -->
        <version>${jjwt-api.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- bootstrap and jquery -->
    ...
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Here is my Security Configuration. The following configuration is working. But please note that I have comment out the `//@Bean` above the  `public ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository()` in `OAuth2LoginWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`.

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
    prePostEnabled = true, 
    order = 0, 
    mode = AdviceMode.PROXY,
    proxyTargetClass = false
)
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration  {

    private static final String KEY_STORE_FILE = "oauth2/basit-jwt.jks";
    private static final String KEY_STORE_PASSWORD = "basit-pass";
    private static final String KEY_ALIAS = "basit-oauth-jwt";

    @Autowired 
    private UserPrincipalService userPrincipalService;

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    };
 
    @Autowired
    protected void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder builder) throws Exception {
         builder
             .userDetailsService(this.userPrincipalService)
                 .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder())
         .and()
             .eraseCredentials(true);
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public static class ApiWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
        @Override
        @Bean
        public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
            return super.authenticationManagerBean();
        }
    
        @Bean
        public KeyPair keyPair() {
            ClassPathResource ksFile = new ClassPathResource(KEY_STORE_FILE);
            KeyStoreKeyFactory ksFactory = new KeyStoreKeyFactory(ksFile, KEY_STORE_PASSWORD.toCharArray());
            KeyPair keyPair = ksFactory.getKeyPair(KEY_ALIAS);
            return keyPair;
        }
    
        @Override
        public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
            web.ignoring().antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**");
        }
    
        @Bean
        public OpaqueTokenIntrospector introspector() {
            return new JwtOpaqueTokenIntrospector();
        }
    
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity apiHttpSecurity) throws Exception {
        
            apiHttpSecurity.httpBasic().disable()
            .formLogin(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .antMatcher("/api/**")
            .authorizeRequests(
                    authorize -> authorize.mvcMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/oauth2/token").permitAll()
                        .mvcMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/oauth2/introspect").permitAll()
                        .mvcMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/message").hasAuthority("READ")  
                        .mvcMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/message").hasAuthority("WRITE")
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::opaqueToken)
            .sessionManagement(sessionManagement -> 
                sessionManagement.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS));
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @PropertySource("application-oauth2.properties")
    @Order(2)
    public static class OAuth2LoginWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
        // additional configuration for non-Spring Boot projects
        private static List<String> clients = Arrays.asList("google", "facebook", "zapier");
    
        private static String CLIENT_PROPERTY_KEY = "spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.";
    
        @Autowired
        private Environment env;
    
        //@Bean
        public ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository() {
        
            List<ClientRegistration> registrations = clients.stream()
                    .map(c -> getRegistration(c))
                    .filter(registration -> registration != null)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
        
            return new InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository(registrations);
        }
    
        private ClientRegistration getRegistration(String client) {
        
            String clientId = env.getProperty(CLIENT_PROPERTY_KEY + client + ".client-id");

            if (clientId == null) {
                return null;
            }

            String clientSecret = env.getProperty(CLIENT_PROPERTY_KEY + client + ".client-secret");
            if (client.equals("google")) {
                return CommonOAuth2Provider.GOOGLE.getBuilder(client)
                    .clientId(clientId)
                    .clientSecret(clientSecret)
                    .build();
            }
        
            if (client.equals("facebook")) {
                return CommonOAuth2Provider.FACEBOOK.getBuilder(client)
                    .clientId(clientId)
                    .clientSecret(clientSecret)
                    .build();
            }

            if (client.equals("zapier")) {
                ClientRegistration zapierClientRegistration = zapierClientRegistration();
                return zapierClientRegistration;
            }
        
            return null;
        }
    
        private static ClientRegistration zapierClientRegistration() {
            return ClientRegistration.withRegistrationId("zapier")
                .clientId("zapier") 
                .clientSecret("Zapier")
                .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.POST)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
                .redirectUriTemplate("https://zapier.com/dashboard/auth/")
                .scope("openid", "profile", "email", "address", "phone")
                .authorizationUri("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth")
                .tokenUri("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token")     
                .userInfoUri("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo")
                .userNameAttributeName(IdTokenClaimNames.SUB)
                .jwkSetUri("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs")
                .clientName("Zapier")                               
                .build();
        }
    
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity oauthHttpSecurity) throws Exception {
        
            oauthHttpSecurity
                .antMatcher("/oauth2/**")
                .authorizeRequests(
                    authorize -> authorize.mvcMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/oauth2/login").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .oauth2Login();
            //.oauth2Login(oauth2 -> 
                   oauth2.clientRegistrationRepository(clientRegistrationRepository())
                //.loginPage("/oauth2/login")
            //);
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    public static class FormLoginWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
        @Bean
        protected SessionRegistry sessionRegistryImpl() {
            return new SessionRegistryImpl();
        }
    
        ///Very important ,you wont login again after logout if you dont include this
        @Bean
        public ServletListenerRegistrationBean<HttpSessionEventPublisher> httpSessionEventPublisher() {
            return new ServletListenerRegistrationBean<HttpSessionEventPublisher>(new HttpSessionEventPublisher());
        }
    
        @Bean
        public CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository(){
            HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository repository = new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository();
            return repository;
        }
    
        @Override
        public void configure(WebSecurity security) {
            security.ignoring().antMatchers("/css/**", "/img/**", "/webjars/**", "/favicon.ico");
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity security) throws Exception {
        
            security
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/session/list").hasAuthority("VIEW_USER_SESSIONS")
                      
                // Any request simply requires authentication, regardless of permissions.
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
            .and()
                .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .failureUrl("/login?loginFailed")
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/ticket/list")
                    .usernameParameter("username")
                    .passwordParameter("password")
                    .permitAll()
            .and()
                .logout()
                    .logoutUrl("/logout")
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?loggedOut")
                    .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                    .clearAuthentication(true)
                    .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                    .permitAll()
            .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                    .sessionFixation()
                    .changeSessionId()
                    .maximumSessions(1)
                    .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true)
                    .sessionRegistry(this.sessionRegistryImpl())
                .and()
            .and()
                .csrf()
                    .csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository())
                    .requireCsrfProtectionMatcher((r) -> {
                        String m = r.getMethod();
                        return !r.getServletPath().startsWith("/api/") && ("POST".equals(m) || "PUT".equals(m) ||
                                    "DELETE".equals(m) || "PATCH".equals(m));
                    });
        }
    }
}
```

But if I open `@Bean` on `public ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository()` in `OAuth2LoginWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`. I get the following error

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfiguration.FormLoginWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setContentNegotationStrategy' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setConfigurers' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.OAuth2ClientConfiguration$OAuth2ClientWebMvcSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setAuthorizedClientRepository' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'authorizedClientRepository' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/oauth2/client/servlet/OAuth2WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'authorizedClientRepository' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'authorizedClientService' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/oauth2/client/servlet/OAuth2WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'authorizedClientService' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfiguration.OAuth2LoginWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setContentNegotationStrategy' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mvcContentNegotiationManager': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:723) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:130) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1422) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setConfigurers' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.OAuth2ClientConfiguration$OAuth2ClientWebMvcSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setAuthorizedClientRepository' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'authorizedClientRepository' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/oauth2/client/servlet/OAuth2WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'authorizedClientRepository' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'authorizedClientService' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/oauth2/client/servlet/OAuth2WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'authorizedClientService' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfiguration.OAuth2LoginWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setContentNegotationStrategy' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mvcContentNegotiationManager': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:723) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:130) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1422) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.OAuth2ClientConfiguration$OAuth2ClientWebMvcSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setAuthorizedClientRepository' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'authorizedClientRepository' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/oauth2/client/servlet/OAuth2WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'authorizedClientRepository' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'authorizedClientService' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/oauth2/client/servlet/OAuth2WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'authorizedClientService' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfiguration.OAuth2LoginWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setContentNegotationStrategy' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mvcContentNegotiationManager': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:723) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:130) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1422) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'authorizedClientRepository' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/oauth2/client/servlet/OAuth2WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'authorizedClientRepository' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'authorizedClientService' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/oauth2/client/servlet/OAuth2WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'authorizedClientService' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfiguration.OAuth2LoginWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setContentNegotationStrategy' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mvcContentNegotiationManager': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:797) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:538) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'authorizedClientService' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/oauth2/client/servlet/OAuth2WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'authorizedClientService' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfiguration.OAuth2LoginWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setContentNegotationStrategy' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mvcContentNegotiationManager': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:797) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:538) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfiguration.OAuth2LoginWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setContentNegotationStrategy' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mvcContentNegotiationManager': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:723) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:130) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1422) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mvcContentNegotiationManager': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.beforeSingletonCreation(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:347) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:219) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1304) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
```

What I am doing wrong here. Default is working but exposing `ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository() as bean` causing this error.

Is there any other settings that I need to expose here ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you or someone else found a solution for this problem?

Comment: yup I have solved it. Sorry I didn't post a solution but it is a configuration issue. That's why I got this error. Are you trying to configure oauth2 with spring boot ? Because experimental oauth2 server has been launched. https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security.experimental/spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server/0.0.3 .

Comment: Actually when I was trying this. At that time spring oauth2 server didn't launch. Although it was experimental but I used it because it was fulfilling my requirement. I also customized the experimental oauth2 server on my own because right now it doesn't provide Password Credentails Grant type. Also I customize it to configure token time too. But I used it because I knew that by and by new versions will launch and ultimately one day it will release. At that time I will remove my customization and use spring oauth2 configuration.

Answer (score 0):

It is better not to create beans inside the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` implementation. Create all your beans in a separate general configuration and reference them using `@Autowired`, for example:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class SpringConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public OpaqueTokenIntrospector introspector() {
        return new JwtOpaqueTokenIntrospector();
    }
}
```

and then define `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` inside an another file:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class ApiWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    protected OpaqueTokenIntrospector opaqueTokenIntrospector;

    .... here is the code which uses token introspector ....
}
```